# Modify list view column titles in a view without changing the list columns

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, view, client-side-rendering

I have a page that contains list view web part. I want to rename the column titles.

I have used the following JS script, however it only shows if I click on it. Also, the id of the list view title changes sometimes.

Is there a way on how to implement this successfully?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//This script is developed by Mohammad Yusuf Hussain # http://mohammadyusufhussain-sharepoint.blogspot.in/
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ChangeColumnName"); // Call ChangeColumnName function on PageLoad
    function ChangeColumnName() 
    {
        RenameColumn('diid8SortAuthor', 'Author'); //Provide Column ID and New Column name
    }
    function RenameColumn(colID, NewHeader) {
        try {
            document.getElementById(colID).innerHTML = NewHeader; //Change Header Name
            document.getElementById(colID).title = "Sort by " + NewHeader; // Change Tooltip value
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert('Invalid Column ID:' + colID);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE - JS function to loop through column titles:**

```
            function modifyColumns(renderCtx)
{
  var arrayLength= renderCtx.ListSchema.Field.length;

    for (var i=0; i < arrayLength;i++)
    {
        if(renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i] == 'order_number')
        {
            var newTitle= "New Title";
            var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i];
            linkTitleField.DisplayName = newTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: @TaranGoel sharepoint 2013

Comment: Please try my answer below.

Comment: renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i] returns object, you'll need to refer the "DisplayName" property of it to actually do the compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I am assuming that you're using SharePoint 2013.

I would suggest you to use SharePoint's Client Side Rendering Framework. I would suggest this [blog](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/) to understand how to apply CSR.

The code which you can write to modify column names is as below (I am currently modifying "Title"):

```
(function () {


    function preTaskFormRenderer(renderCtx) {
       modifyColumns(renderCtx);       
    }


    function modifyColumns(renderCtx)
    {
      var arrayLength= renderCtx.ListSchema.Field.length;
        for (var i=0; i < arrayLength;i++)
        {
           if(renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i].DisplayName == 'order_number')
             {
               var newTitle= "New Title";
               var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i];
               linkTitleField.DisplayName = newTitle;
             }
         }
    }

    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var ctxForm = {};
      ctxForm.Templates = {};
      ctxForm.OnPreRender = preTaskFormRenderer;
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

You can also for loop to find position of a particular field. 
var linkTitleField = renderCtx.**ListSchema.Field[0]**;
Here "0" refers to the position of the field. As i mentioned above you can iterate over the fields to find the position of the desired column.

Comment: I don't have 'Title' field. how do I specify which field in your code? `var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[0];` here?

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look at it. If you want I can add the For loop too.

Comment: can you help me write the loop? see the loop i created in the question.

Comment: Also I have a question; I have two list web parts on the same page, I want to render the second list web part but it only renders the first one. how do I tell it to render the second one? The two web parts are linked

Comment: You need to update the JSlink property of the webpart which you want to custom render. I'll update the answer with loop. Thanks