# How to customize a column's display name on a per-view basis

Tags: list-view, column, display-name

Is it possible to have the column display name change depending on which view is shown? When I change the display name of the column it applies to all views.

The main reason for doing this is some views need to have more columns than others, and I need to use abbreviations to shrink the column width. However, these views mostly apply to "super users" and regular views will benefit from having the non-abbreviated column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use CSR via JSLink to customize the display names of your columns on a per-view basis.

Here are some MSDN CSR code samples to get you started:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

EDIT:
Similar thread: [Modify list view column titles in a view without changing the list columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147011/modify-list-view-column-titles-in-a-view-without-changing-the-list-columns)

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for. I particularly found this sub-link useful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Do you have any recommendations on best practices for deploying/debugging CSR? I find using a script editor web part to be a bit ineffective.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the late reply, but you can always create the JS file and then drop it into Site Assets, and reference it on the page via the JS link attribute of your list view web part. So, when you are editing the page that contains your list view, just go to the bottom of the web part property pane, and then add your reference.